# How to set communication range in meters in related .cc files of the Inet 4.4

Tags: omnet++, inet

How to set communication range in meters in related .cc files of  the Inet 4.4?
I don't mean in ini files such as omnetpp.ini.
For a more precise and clear explanation, when the following command in omnetpp.ini is run, which functions are called from which files to execute this command?

```
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 250m
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Lines in an INI file are not commands. They are not executed. Instead whenever a module is initialized, it queries the WHOLE ini file and if it finds a matching line, it can read that value. If you are looking for the place where this INI file value is queried, the you should search the source for `par("communicationRange")`. You will find it most likely in a radio module's `initialize()` method.

Comment: Thanks @Rudi, I want to set the communicationRange by c++ command in simulation runtime in the .cc files of the INET. For example, by coding at the Inet, let's say that the communication range of an arbitrary node will increase by one meter every second from the start of the simulation.